# How to process data larger than memory in R locally?

Tags: r, apache-spark, memory, sparklyr

I have 83GB of data in the shape of CSVs stored in `AWS S3`. Usually I would use a `Spark` implementation in R (`sparklyr`) in `AWS EMR` to process the job granting enough memory.

However, I am not able to access my `AWS EMR` account (for the purpose of this question, imagine I will not be able to in the near future). What are some good alternatives in `R` to do the same processing without my memory crashing (even if it takes long)?

Comment: The go-to solution seems to be [arrow](https://cran.r-project.org/package=arrow) but it only supports a [subset of R functions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/acero.html).

Comment: You might want to check arrow and duckdb. Or, depending on your background and available hardware resources, perhaps set up a local spark instance (depending on the task itself and partitioning, your RAM requirements really shouldn't reach anywhere close to that 80GB range)

Comment: I am a bit experienced with `arrow`. However, for some recent data processing tasks I've done, if the datasets were larger than memory and there were many operations, R crashed (at least in Visual Studio Code). For some chunks where the errors ocurred, I relied on `arrow::map_batches`. This did not crash, but it didn't do the whole required aggregations (e.g., group by week and other vars and summarise numeric variables), so I needed to rerun the group by again after it. Any thoughts on this @margusl?

Comment: Batch processing is currently experimental and must say I have no first hand experience with this. Though what I'd look into first is moving from CSV to partitioned parquete files. There's a good chance my understanding is overly simplified or just naive, i.e. coming up with a partitioning strategy that's optimal for your aggregations and common filters might not be so straightforward.  Among other resources there's [Working with multi-file data sets vignette](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html) and Arrow chapter in upcomping R4DS 2e - https://r4ds.hadley.nz/arrow.html